# Anaconda / Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve

Tags: python, anaconda

I tried to install a package for anaconda and this message showed up:

Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: | failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

After that, it searched for conflicts which i cancelled after several hours. The recommended fix is to downgrade python with conda install python=3.7.5 for example however the same problem occurs doing that.
I tried to reinstall anaconda but the same message shows up when I try to install anything.
I am quite new to all of this and I am out of ideas what I can do. Any suggestions what I can do?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The reply is 3 months late and I don't have any information about what you're trying to install but I ran into the same errors (I'm also first time conda user). And the easiest workaround for me was to create a new [environment](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html). And remember to install everything you need with one command as it can get messy with the dependency tree if you install packages one by one.

e.g. I ran

```
conda create -n pacbio pbmm2 whatshap
```