# Why isn't Opencv downloading?

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

I typed in the code (conda install -c conda-forge opencv) into the anaconda prompt, and when it starts to download it freezes at solving environment and tries again in an endless cycle.
this is what it says

```
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Anaconda / Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67843233/anaconda-solving-environment-failed-with-initial-frozen-solve-retrying-with)

Comment: just `pip3 install opencv-python`. that's the official package. conda-forge lags behind by several versions and it's only an automatic build from the same sources as the official one.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz in what world is conda-forges 4.5.5 lacking behind the latest release from https://opencv.org/releases/ (4.5.5)?

Comment: a month or so ago, when I last looked, it was still at 4.5.3, while 4.5.4 had been out for several months. anyway, still no reason not to use the official build. they may now put some effort into putting decent packages into the conda ecosystem/namespace but it used to be awfully polluted with random "opencv' packages. conda-forge is a noble effort but I don't see any reason to duplicate PyPI. what's your affiliation with conda/anaconda/conda-forge?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a series of steps to solve this problem without solution. Until i had to use "albumentation" module for another AI project, and this library brings openCV and it solves my problem.

conda install -c conda-forge albumentations

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).